# Timepicker seems to crash My App on Samsung Devices With Android Version 6.0.1

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash, timepicker

I am facing a very annoying situation. I am trying display an alert dialog with DatePicker and TimePicker. It works on every device except some Samsung Devices (And according to the crash reports I received, all of them are Android Version 6.0.1).

Here is the crash report:

```
USER_COMMENT=null
STACK_TRACE=android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.TimePicker
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
at ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.ManageTransactions.askTimestamp(ManageTransactions.java:385)
at ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.ManageTransactions$3.onClick(ManageTransactions.java:324)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22538)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.TimePicker
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.widget.TimePicker$TimePickerDelegate.onRtlPropertiesChanged(int)' on a null object reference
at android.widget.TimePicker.onRtlPropertiesChanged(TimePicker.java:248)
at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resolvePadding(ViewGroup.java:6877)
at android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(View.java:5342)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4677)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:591)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:78)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:74)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:70)
... 24 more
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.TimePicker
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
at ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.ManageTransactions.askTimestamp(ManageTransactions.java:385)
at ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.ManageTransactions$3.onClick(ManageTransactions.java:324)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22538)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.widget.TimePicker$TimePickerDelegate.onRtlPropertiesChanged(int)' on a null object reference
at android.widget.TimePicker.onRtlPropertiesChanged(TimePicker.java:248)
at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resolvePadding(ViewGroup.java:6877)
at android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(View.java:5342)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4677)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:591)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:78)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:74)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:70)
... 24 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
at ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.ManageTransactions.askTimestamp(ManageTransactions.java:385)
at ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.ManageTransactions$3.onClick(ManageTransactions.java:324)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22538)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.widget.TimePicker$TimePickerDelegate.onRtlPropertiesChanged(int)' on a null object reference
at android.widget.TimePicker.onRtlPropertiesChanged(TimePicker.java:248)
at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resolvePadding(ViewGroup.java:6877)
at android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(View.java:5342)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4677)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:591)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:78)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:74)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:70)
... 24 more
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.widget.TimePicker$TimePickerDelegate.onRtlPropertiesChanged(int)' on a null object reference
at android.widget.TimePicker.onRtlPropertiesChanged(TimePicker.java:248)
at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resolvePadding(ViewGroup.java:6877)
at android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(View.java:5342)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4677)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:591)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:78)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:74)
at android.widget.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:70)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
at ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.ManageTransactions.askTimestamp(ManageTransactions.java:385)
at ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.ManageTransactions$3.onClick(ManageTransactions.java:324)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22538)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

CUSTOM_DATA=
PHONE_MODEL=SAMSUNG-SM-T377A
BRAND=samsung
ANDROID_VERSION=6.0.1
APP_VERSION_NAME=3.1.0
```

Here is my code:

```
public void askTimestamp(final String transaction_type, final String item_name, final int integerItems, final EditText item_count, final int newItemCount, final TextView textBox_count)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Enter Transaction Details");
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_time, null);
    final CustomDatePicker datePicker = (CustomDatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.done), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            String day = "";
            String month = "";
            String year = "";
            String hours = "";
            String minutes = "";
            String seconds = "00";
            day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth() + "";
            if (day.length() == 1)
            {
                day = "0" + day;
            }
            int actualMonth = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
            month = actualMonth + "";
            if (month.length() == 1)
            {
                month = "0" + month;
            }
            year = datePicker.getYear() + "";
            if (year.length() == 3)
            {
                year = "0" + year;
            }
            else if(year.length() == 2)
            {
                year = "00" + year;
            }
            else if(year.length() == 1)
            {
                year = "000" + year;
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                hours = timePicker.getHour() + "";
                minutes = timePicker.getMinute() + "";
            }
            else
            {
                hours = timePicker.getCurrentHour() + "";
                minutes = timePicker.getCurrentMinute() + "";
            }
            if (hours.length() == 1)
            {
                hours = "0" + hours;
            }
            if (minutes.length() == 1)
            {
                minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }
            String dateTime = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            dbHelper.updateItem(item_name, newItemCount);
            dbHelper.createTransaction(transaction_type, item_name, integerItems, dateTime);
            if (transaction_type.equals("add"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(MyApp.getContext(), getString(R.string.transaction_adding) + " " + item_name.trim() + " " + getString(R.string.succeeded) + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MyApp.getContext(), getString(R.string.transaction_removing) + " " + item_name.trim() + " " + getString(R.string.succeeded) + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            item_count.setText("");
            textBox_count.setText(newItemCount + "");
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog_created = dialog.create();
    if (!this.isFinishing())
    {
        dialog_created.show();
    }
}
```

And here is the layout I am trying to inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.CustomDatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    </ankit.inventory.ankitarora.inventorymanagementsimple.CustomDatePicker>

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    </TimePicker>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please Help!

PS: I received this crash report using ACRA crash reporting system in my app.

Comment: Looks like OS problem, according to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75877) you can MAYBE mitigate it by using stub-view, and inflate `TimePicker` view either programmatically or from other layout, set it correct LayoutParams object, and try to inject such inflated view to original layout to replace the stub (can't think of anything simpler at the moment, nor have I any idea whether this will really fix it).

Comment: Hi .. What I have done for the workaround is that, I am inflating another layout in a catch statement, and putting the above inflate part in a try block. So, for now, I am putting a default time of 12:00:00 and not allowing the user to select time for transaction. I will try the suggestions given here..

Comment: Did you keep this workaround or did you find another solution?

Comment: I kept this workaround. Did not find any other solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely, I started seeing this crash only recently. My attempted workaround is to subclass TimePicker and catch the crash. Unfortunately I do not have access to any of the affected devices (Galaxy J1, Galaxy J3, Galaxy On7 Pro, Galaxy A7) for validating this approach.

```
class TimePicker(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : android.widget.TimePicker(context, attrs) {
    override fun onRtlPropertiesChanged(layoutDirection: Int) {
        try {
            super.onRtlPropertiesChanged(layoutDirection)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }
    }
}
```